# How to code the maximum set packing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, set, disjoint-sets

Suppose we have a finite set S and a list of subsets of S. Then, the set packing problem asks if some k subsets in the list are pairwise disjoint .
The optimization version of the problem, maximum set packing, asks for the maximum number of pairwise disjoint sets in the list.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing

So, Let `S  = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

```
and `Sa = {1,2,3,4}`
and `Sb = {4,5,6}`
and `Sc = {5,6,7,8}`
and `Sd = {9,10}`
```

Then the maximum number of pairwise disjoint sets are 3 ( Sa, Sc, Sd )

I could not find any articles about the algorithm involved. Can you shed some light on the same?

My approach:

Sort the sets according to the size. Start from the set of the smallest size. If no element of the next set intersects with the current set, then we unite the set and increase the count of maximum sets. Does this sound good to you? Any better ideas?

Comment: It won't get you the optimum, but could provide a good approximation

Comment: Are your sets all contiguous ranges of numbers?

Comment: @ Niklas - Yes, the numbers are contiguous {1 to 30000+}

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. The subsets are sorted in asc order but the numbers may not be contiguous. The original set is a list of contiguous numbers

Comment: Integer programming, unless the sets are very regular (e.g., they're derived from the social golfer problem), in which case constraint programming.

Comment: How many sets do you have? There's a simple O(2^n) algorithm for the problem

Comment: You can also use any general independent set algorithm for this.

Comment: @Niklas - I have about 20 to 25 sets. You mean I should use the brute force method of find the least intersecting set at each iteration?

Comment: @user3080029: There's a trivial `O(2^n * n^2)` algorithm. There's a slightly more involved `O(2^n)` algorithm. Independent set algorithms can be as good as `O(1.3^n)` or something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As hivert pointed out, this problem is NP-hard, so there's no efficient way to do this. However, if your input is relatively small, you can still pull it off. Exponential doesn't mean impossible, after all. It's just that exponential problems become impractical very quickly, as the input size grows. But for something like 25 sets, you can easily brute force it.

Here's one approach. Let's say you have *n* subsets, called *S0*, *S1*, ..., etc. We can try every combination of subsets, and pick the one with maximum cardinality. There are only 2^25 = 33554432 choices, so this is probably reasonable enough.

An easy way to do this is to notice that any non-negative number strictly below 2^N represents a particular choice of subsets. Look at the binary representation of the number, and choose the sets whose indices correspond to the bits that are on. So if the number is 11, the 0th, 1st and 3rd bits are on, and this corresponds to the combination [S0, S1, S3]. Then you just verify that these three sets are in fact disjoint.

Your procedure is as follows:

1. Iterate i from 0 to 2^N - 1
2. For each value of i, use the bits that are on to figure out the corresponding combination of subsets.
3. If those subsets are pairwise disjoint, update your best answer with this combination (i.e., use this if it is bigger than your current best).

Alternatively, use backtracking to generate your subsets. The two approaches are equivalent, modulo implementation tradeoffs. Backtracking will have some stack overhead, but can cut off entire lines of computation if you check disjointness as you go. For example, if S1 and S2 are not disjoint, then it will never bother with any bigger combinations containing those two, saving some time. The iterative method can't optimize itself in this way, but is fast and efficient because of the bitwise operations and tight loop.

The only nontrivial matter here is how to check if the subsets are pairwise disjoint. There are all sorts of tricks you can pull here as well, depending on the constraints.

A simple approach is to start with an empty set structure (pick whatever you want from the language of your choice) and add elements from each subset one by one. If you ever hit an element that's already in the set, then it occurs in at least two subsets, and you can give up on this combination.

If the original set *S* has *m* elements, and *m* is relatively small, you can map each of them to the range [0, m-1] and use bitmasks for each set. So if *m <= 64*, you can use a Java long to represent each subset. Turn on all the bits that correspond to the elements in the subset. This allows blazing fast set operation, because of the speed of bitwise operations. Bitwise AND corresponds to set intersection, and bitwise OR is a union. You can check if two subsets are disjoint by seeing if the intersection is empty (i.e., ANDing the two bitmasks gives you 0).

If you don't have so few elements, you can still avoid repeating the set intersections multiple times. You have very few sets, so precompute which ones are disjoint at the start. You can just store a boolean matrix D, such that D[i][j] = true iff i and j are disjoint. Then you just look up all pairs in a combination to verify pairwise disjointness, rather than doing real set operations.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the set packing problem searching a [Maximum independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_independent_set#Finding_maximum_independent_sets). You encode your problem as follows:

- for each set you put a vertex
- you put an edge between two vertex if they share a common number.

Then you wan't a maximum set of vertex without two having two related vertex. Unfortunately this is a NP-Hard problem. Any know algorithm is exponential.

Comment: should I use the brute force method of find the least intersecting set at each iteration? I have about 25 sets

Comment: 25 is probably feasible by brute force. They are many package out there that do that (In Sagemath we use NetworkX). On the opposite, I you write it yourself, I suggest you find the good data structure to allows fast backtracking. Maybe Knuth [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) is a good option.

Comment: Advertisement: I just checked, the one which is in Sagemath seems to easily solve the problem for random graph of size 100.

Comment: Solve using independent set problem. I solved similar problem using it.

Comment: @coderhacker This misses some opportunities for shortcuts, see https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/86848/83094.