# Selecting Maximum Number of Choice

Tags: algorithm

We are given N fruits and M choices to select those fruits.M lines have some integers and the first one is K and each M lines follows K integers after the first value (ie. K) denoting the indices of fruit to be selected in that choice.
I need to find out the maximal number of choices that can be selected.

Note :- There is only one fruit at a particular index.

Sample Input:-

4 3

2 1 2

2 2 3

2 3 4

Output :-

2

As we can select 1st and 3rd choice.

Which Algorithm should I use to solve this question ?

Comment: This is obviously Homework. Any attempt to share ? Any knowledge about graph theory ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272445/how-to-code-the-maximum-set-packing-algorithm/22275179#22275179

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the maximum independent set

There are very well detailed algorithms for finding maximum independent set in this paper:
[Algorithms  for  Maximum  independent  Sets](http://wwwold.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/sat/robson.pdf)

And a parallel approach has been provided in this one:[Lecture Notes on a Parallel Algorithm for Generating a Maximal Independent Set](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vigoda/7530-Spring10/MIS.pdf)

And [this](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~speque/mll-plugin/multilevelLayoutPlugin/MaximalIndependentSetFinder.java) is a java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [set packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing), one of the classic NP-complete problems. There is no efficient solution, but you can try a backtracking algorithm (slow but exact) or a greedy approximation (fast but suboptimal).